# slope and intercept issue in scatterplot ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, lm

I was drawing a regression line (linear) using `mtcars` dataset (`mpg ~ cyl`). I ran a simple linear model using `mpg` and `cyl` and executed a summary.

Intercept from the linear model summary does not match with the graphical representation.

I am having hard time understanding what is going on. If I use R's base plotting function to draw the scatterplot, I get the same result as ggplot2. I changed the y-axis scale limit (0, 40) without any success.

Here is my code

```
data(mtcars)
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=cyl, y=mpg)) + geom_point(shape=1) # create graph
p + geom_smooth(method = lm, se=FALSE) # add line
lm.car <- lm(mpg ~ cyl) # create linear model
summary(lm.car) # summary
```

[image: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/213/scatterplot.png/]

Here is linear model output

```
> summary(lm.car)

Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ cyl)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-4.9814 -2.1185  0.2217  1.0717  7.5186 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  37.8846     2.0738   18.27  < 2e-16

cyl          -2.8758     0.3224   -8.92 6.11e-10 

Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

Residual standard error: 3.206 on 30 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared: 0.7262, Adjusted R-squared: 0.7171 
F-statistic: 79.56 on 1 and 30 DF,  p-value: 6.113e-10
```

Based on following suggestions I used

```
data(mtcars)
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=cyl, y=mpg)) + geom_point(shape=1) +
    xlim(0, 10)# create graph
p + geom_smooth(method = lm, se=FALSE) # add line
```

Here is the ouput:
[image: desired graphical output]

Comment: @Julius: Thanks for formatting help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do regression analysis `Intercept` value shows how large will be `y` value if `x` value is 0. In case of `cyl` and `mpg` `Intercep`t value 37.8846 means that `mpg` will be 37.8846 if `cyl` value is O.

On the `ggplot2` plot regression line only shows values of `cyl` from 4 to 6 (as there are no other values).

If you calculate predicted value of `mpg` for `cyl` value of `4` you will get 26.38142. That's the value you see on plot.

```
predict(lm.car,data.frame(cyl=4))
       1 
26.38142
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It helped a lot in understanding the nature of the problem. From your explanation, I gathered that I should use `xlim(0, 10)`. That resolved the issue. Thanks again.